# How to process the nested JSON with Apache Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have a complex json file with Aggregate and array type objects.
I want to parse this JSON file and may be put in to a case class or class representation of the JSON file.

My JSON file

```
[
{
  "organization": {
    "id": "897330837",

    /*  Aggregate, array*/
    "tradeStyleNames":[
      { "name":"Letra Ativa",
        "priority":1
      }
    ],

    //required Aggregate, array
    "telephone": [
      {
        "telephoneNumber":"9836673812",
        "isdCode":"US, '44' for the UK, '91",
        "isUnreachable":true

      },
      {
        "telephoneNumber":"909812345",
        "isdCode":"US, '44' for the UK, '91"

      }
    ],

    //Required  Aggregate, array or atomic
    "primaryAddress": [
        {"line1": "xyz"},
        {"line2": "xyz"},

    ]


}

},
{
  "organization": {
    "id": "1234",

    /*  Aggregate, array no data under this array*/

    "tradeStyleNames":[],


    //required Aggregate, array
    "telephone": [
      {
        "telephoneNumber":"9836673812"
        //isdCode and isUnreachable are not here

      },
    ],
    // Aggregate, array or atomic
    // instead of array only assign string type 
    **"primaryAddress": "abcd"**

}
}
]
```

## --------------------------------------

Using apache spark 1.6 with scala. Json file size will be 30-40 GG

Please help me - how I process this file in the most efficient way.
I also refer below 2 links but not sure- how it will work in my json file

Comment: do you have a preference of python or scala? (or i guessss, R or java)

Comment: apache spark with scala ....  beacuse I have to store the JSON object to a denormalised table in Habse